# Long equation doesn't go to a new line

Tags: math-mode, spacing, equations

I'm trying to write an equation and make it a little bigger but it's too long and it doesn't go to a new line. I also get some errors on the last line like "Missing $ inserted. \end{equation}} "Bad math environment delimeter. \end{equation}}" "You can't use \eqno in restricted horizontalmode. \end{equation}}"

```
\scalebox{1.0}{%
\begin{equation}

        \bm{f(x, y, z, w)} = (x+y+z+\overline{w}) \cdot (x+y+\overline{z}+\overline{w}) \cdot (x+\overline{y}+z+w) \cdot (x+\overline{y}+\overline{z}+\overline{w}) \cdot (\overline{x}+y+z+w)
        \cdot (\overline{x}+y+\overline{z}+w) \cdot (\overline{x}+\overline{y}+\overline{z}+w) \cdot (\overline{x}+\overline{y}+\overline{z}+\overline{w})
        

\end{equation}}
```

Comment: Welcome! You have a lot of (basic) errors here. Why don't you look at https://www.learnlatex.org/en/lesson-10 ? It's well-spent time, believe me.

Comment: Basically: 1) always post *complete*, compilable examples, with a minimal preamble etc. 2) *never* scale things that way 3) you can't put paragraphs (blank lines) in equations.

Comment: Ok thanks this is my first time using latex and posting questions on stackexchange. I'll look your link thanks

Comment: You're welcome. Try to follow this guide:https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that when posting a question, and you'll help us to help you!

Comment: One last thing, could you tell me how to scale things?

Comment: You don't generally scale things with fonts; you use a different font size if you want bigger/smaller equations. But the details on how to do it depend on: class used, packages used, preamble details... see why a *complete example* is needed? (Moreover, remember the LaTeX philosophy: you concentrate on the *content*, the appearance is chosen by the documentclass author (journal, conference, etc.).)

Comment: Yea unfortunately that's not the case for me because I have to do a project alone for university

Comment: Never ignore errors, any pdf produced after an error is just a debugging aid, not intended to be usable.

Comment: Well, try to add a complete *minimal* example, and we'll try to help.

Comment: Do also consider replacing all instances of `\overline{...}` with `\bar{...}`.

Comment: @Mico thanks for the suggestion but I prefer `\overline`, the line is bigger so you can see it more clearly

Comment: @pepper  - The downside of using `\overline` notation, at least in the present context, is that the product of `\overline{x}` and `\overline{y}`, written as `\overline{x}\overline{y}`, is indistinguishable from `\overline{xy}`. This doesn't happen if you use `\bar` notation, *viz.*, `\bar{x}\bar{y}`.

Comment: @Mico oh ok thanks, for that problem I wrote `\overline{x}\:\overline{y}\` so there is a little space between the two

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`equation` is a display construct that adds vertical space so can not be used in `\scalebox` (you should anyway avoid scaling text) also `equation` will give an error if a blank line appears in the source.

You should never ignore error messages, TeX can sometimes recover if you scroll past an error but only to allow further debugging, the pdf output is never usable after an error.

Here you could use a multi-line math display, several possibilities depending on how you want it to look but...
[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bm,amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{multline}
  \bm{f(x, y, z, w)} = \\
  (x+y+z+\overline{w}) \cdot (x+y+\overline{z}+\overline{w}) \cdot (x+\overline{y}+z+w) \cdot
  (x+\overline{y}+\overline{z}+\overline{w}) \\
   \cdot  (\overline{x}+y+z+w)
  \cdot (\overline{x}+y+\overline{z}+w) \cdot (\overline{x}+\overline{y}+\overline{z}+w) \cdot 
  (\overline{x}+\overline{y}+\overline{z}+\overline{w})
\end{multline}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, I solved the new line problem using \begin{align*} but I can't find a better solution for the scaling problem. Now I have used \large in front of the equation and it works but other than that and \scalebox I don't know other alternatives.
Of course I wasn't ignoring error messages, I wrote them because I thougth that it could be usefull. Thank you again for the solution, I'll keep it in mind, it could be usefull later

Comment: @pepper yes  `align*` and `multline*` the same here just as I commented in the answer, different layout it's always better to use a fixed size like `\large` to get a consistent foint but you can have any font size `\fontsize{3cm}[4cm}\selectfont` for example (with eg `\usepackage{lmodern}` to allow any size)

Comment: ok thank you I will use this in the future

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}


\begin{document}

\begin{align}
\boldsymbol{f(x, y, z, w)} &= (x+y+z+\overline{w}) \cdot (x+y+\overline{z}+\overline{w}) \cdot (x+\overline{y}+z+w) \cdot{} \nonumber \\
&\quad (x+\overline{y}+\overline{z}+\overline{w}) \cdot (\overline{x}+y+z+w) \cdot (\overline{x}+y+\overline{z}+w) \cdot{} \nonumber \\
&\quad (\overline{x}+\overline{y}+\overline{z}+w) \cdot{(\overline{x}+\overline{y}+\overline{z}+\overline{w})}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: use `\cdot{}` at the end so you get the right space for the final .

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you very much. Is it correct?

Comment: no that's worse!  look at your output, you have no space around the final .   I meant literally use `\cdot{}` for (just) the last two cdot on the line so that the cdot has something after it and stays as a binary operator. You have put some subterm inside braces???

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I hope that you have patience with me. Before I must understood. Can you edit my code to understand it? Please

Comment: just look at your image it should look like `) ⋅`  but your last dot on lines 1 and 2 looks like `)⋅`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Ah peraphs I have understood. Thanks.